# aligning to the left

Tags: align

The following is the script I used.

```
\begin{align*}
(a,b):=\{x:a\prec x\prec b\}\\
(a,b]:=\{x:a\prec x\preceq b\}\cdots\text{if $b$ is the largest element of $X$}
\end{align*}
```

But, I want the $(a,b):={x:a\prec x\prec b}$

to be at the left side aligning with the bottom one. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, then the solution is to use the alignment of environment `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(a,b) & \colonequals \{x:a\prec b\} \\
(a,b] & \colonequals \{x:a\preceq b\}\ \cdots\
        \text{if $b$ is the largest element of $X$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is defined in the `mathtools` package as `\coloneqq`. It is also accessible as a `mathb` symbol, from the `mathabx` package In the following code I show both possibilities, without loading the `mathabx` package, which redefines almost every math symbols.

I take the opportunity to define a `\set` command with braces that can grow with the contents and a proper spacing. It requires `mathtools` (that loads `amsmath`) and `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\usepackage{xparse}

%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}


    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
  <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
  <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
    }{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\bcoloneq}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"15}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
 & \texttt{\textbackslash colonequals}: & (a,b) & \colonequals \set{x:a\prec b} & & \\
 & & (a,b] & \colonequals \set{x:a\preceq b}\ \cdots
         & & \text{if $b$ is the largest element of $X$}\\[8pt]
 & \texttt{\textbackslash coloneqq}: & (a,b) & \coloneqq \set{x:a\prec b} \\
 & & (a,b] & \coloneqq \set*{x:a\preceq b}\ \cdots & & \text{if $b$ is the largest element of $X$}\\[8pt]
 & \texttt{mathabx}: & (a,b) & \bcoloneq \set{x:a\prec b} \\
 & & (a,b] & \bcoloneq \set{x:a\preceq b}\ \cdots & & \text{if $b$ is the largest element of $X$}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]